Can't get secrets from Vault with Hashicorp in Java
I'm using Hashicorp plugin to get secrets from Vault but without success. I have looked through all similar questions here and also in Internet but still haven't solved my issue.
I copied code from Github, set all necessary variables as follows:
            <!-- Read secrets from HashiCorp Vault and assign it to Maven properties -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.github.schereradi</groupId>
                <artifactId>vault-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pull</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>pull</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <servers>
                                <server>
                                    <!-- Update vault server URL with your own URL -->
                                    <url>https://**myVaulUrlHere:8200**</url>
                                    <!-- Token to authenticate with Vault server. Do not hardcode the vault token -->
                                    <token>**myTokenHere**</token>
                                    <paths>
                                        <path>
                                            <!-- Vault path can be hardcoded completely or it can be made dynamic like shown below -->
                                            <name>**myVaultPathHere**</name>
                                            <mappings>
                                                <mapping>
                                                    <!-- key - name of the key stored in vault --
                                                    <key>testUser</key>
                                                    <!-- property - to whom you want to assign the value after reading it from the Vault -->
                                                    <property>username</property>
                                                </mapping>
                                                <mapping>
                                                    <!-- key - name of the key stored in vault -->
                                                    <key>testPassword</key>
                                                    <!-- property - to whom you want to assign the value after reading it from the Vault -->
                                                    <property>password</property>
                                                </mapping>
                                            </mappings>
                                        </path>
                                    </paths>
                                </server>
                            </servers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

and trying to get username and password values from pom in application properties:
prop.username=@username@
prop.password=@password@

Spring boot class:
@RestController
public class ReadSecretsController {

    @Value("${prop.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${prop.password}")
    private String password;


    @GetMapping("/getSecretsFromVault")
    public String getSecretsFromVault() {
        return "Username: " + username + " Password: " + password;
    }
}

The only thing I see when started "localhost:8080/getSecretsFromVault" is
Username: @username@
Password: @password@
I made curl query from localhost to check whether credentials are being pulled properly using token and vault path and it returns JSON with all required info.
I see 2 options here:

Plugin doesn't work properly.
The values aren't passed from pom.xml to application.properties. I have tried some hints such as filtering and delimiter config in pom.xml but with the same result.

    <build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>

                <configuration>
                    <delimiters>
                        <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                    </delimiters>
                    <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Will be gratheful for any piece of advice!

I would like to confirm the usage scenario, (1) Do you want to read the password from Vault during the compilation and packaging period, and then set it to prop.password in application.properties? (2) Or do you want to during the execution period, Read the password from Vault and set it to prop.password?

@life888888 - I suppose, second option. I run my app as JAR file in docker.

I seem to have found out what the problem was - we are using KV Engine v2 and this plugin was designed for KV Engine v1.
I tried with application.properties:
spring.application.name=vaultdemo 
spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled=true 
spring.cloud.vault.authentication=TOKEN 
spring.cloud.vault.token= 
spring.cloud.vault.scheme=http 
spring.cloud.vault.host=127.0.0.1 
spring.cloud.vault.port=8200 
spring.config.import: vault://

but failed as
spring.config.import: vault://

highlights last symbol "/" in red. I learned that it is a bug but found no solution.
